# Extracting prices from html using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors, phpquery

I'm parsing an html document and I need to extract all the prices in it (the format is $99.00). So what I want to do is extract all the elements that contain the substring "Price" (or "price") in its class or id attribute. But I tried using something like $("[class*='Price']") or $("[id*='Price']") and then concatenate the results on an array but the jquery selector part is not working properly, is not finding anything. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a better way to do this? Any suggestions for a better approach?
Thank you.

**UPDATE**:I'm actually using a jQuery port called phpQuery for php.

**UPDATE2**: I don't know the exact class or id of the elements since this is a generic script that I will run on different e-commerce sites, so that's why I'm using the *= wildcard to get all elements (mostly a, div, span, etc, I don't need input).  I figured it out and this is what I have so far:

```
function getPrice($doc){
    phpQuery::selectDocument($doc);
    $prices = array();
    foreach(pq("[class*='Price'], [class*='price'], [id*='Price'], [id*='price']") as $res){    
        $each = pq($res);

        if(preg_match('/\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?/', $each->text(), $matches)){
            echo '<br>'.$matches[0].'</br>';
            $prices[] = $each->html();
        }   
    }
}
```

This is printing the correct elements.  Now I need to extract the font-size of those elements so I can sort the array by font-size.

Comment: Please add jsfiddle of the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select by ID: `$("#Price")`

Select by Class: `$(".Price")`

Showing your HTML would help.

Answer (score 0):

Give this ago

```
$(function(){
    $('.price').each(function(){
        //create your array here of $(this).val() or $(this).html()
    });
});
```

Comment: obviously try this on items with the class price. use $(this).val if its an input or $(this).html if it's a div/span/a/etc :)